# Search for string across range of columns in a grepl ifelse statement

Tags: r

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
immed_cause_death    consq1   consq2    consq3
quetapine            cocaine  heroin    meth
meth                 heroin   thc       alcohol
alcohol              meth
```

I want to create a new column `antipsychotics` - and if a certain string is found in either `immed_cause_death`, `consq1`, `consq2`, or `consq3`, assign it a 1:

```
df$antipsychotics = ifelse(grepl('Quetiapine', df$immed_cause_death, ignore.case = TRUE) |
                                             grepl('Quetiapine', df$consq1, ignore.case = TRUE) |
                                             grepl('Quetiapine', df$consq2, ignore.case = TRUE) |
                                             grepl('Quetiapine', df$consq3, ignore.case = TRUE),1,'')
```

But let's say instead of referencing each column separately, I want to do this more efficiently and search in a range of columns, i.e:

```
search_cols <- c(immed_cause_death, consq1, consq2, consq3)
```

How would I write the same syntax and grep over the search_cols, instead of referencing each column separately?  i.e.:

```
grepl('quetiapine', df[search_cols])
```

Comment: @akrun: regarding the "tagging" of titles, there is a consensus here to leave them off - and that the tag system itself is the best/right place to do that. Here's the current [canonical position](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076) (full disclosure, I wrote it).

Answer (score 1):

We could use `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
search_cols <- c("immed_cause_death", "consq1", "consq2", "consq3")
search_words <- c("quetapine", "cocaine")
pat <- sprintf("\\b(%s)\\b", str_c(search_words, collapse = "|"))

df %>%
   mutate(antipsychotics = +(if_any(all_of(search_cols), 
          ~ str_detect(.x, regex(pat, ignore_case = TRUE)) & !is.na(.x))))
```

-output

```
   immed_cause_death  consq1 consq2  consq3 antipsychotics
1         quetapine cocaine heroin    meth              1
2              meth  heroin    thc alcohol              0
3           alcohol    meth   <NA>    <NA>              0
```

---

Or using `base R` with `Reduce` and `grepl`

```
df$antipsychotics <- +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[search_cols], 
     \(x) grepl(pat, x, ignore.case = TRUE))))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(immed_cause_death = c("quetapine", "meth", "alcohol"
), consq1 = c("cocaine", "heroin", "meth"), consq2 = c("heroin", 
"thc", NA), consq3 = c("meth", "alcohol", NA)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: akrun, how would I do this if I'm searching for multiple keywords, i.e. with an or statement:  'quetiapine' OR 'cocaine'?

Answer (score 1):

You can look up if `rowSums` of boolean is greater than one.

```
key <- 'quetiapine|cocaine'

dat$antipsychotics <- +(rowSums(sapply(dat[search_cols], grepl, pattern=key)) > 0)
#   immed_cause_death  consq1 consq2  consq3 antipsychotics
# 1         quetapine cocaine heroin    meth              1
# 2              meth  heroin    thc alcohol              0
# 3           alcohol    meth   <NA>    <NA>              0
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(immed_cause_death = c("quetapine", "meth", "alcohol"
), consq1 = c("cocaine", "heroin", "meth"), consq2 = c("heroin", 
"thc", NA), consq3 = c("meth", "alcohol", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

search_cols <- c('immed_cause_death', 'consq1', 'consq2', 'consq3')
```

Comment: jay.sf - thanks - can there be an argument for ignore case in the solution you provided?

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 Yes, just adapt the regex slightly: `[Qq]uetiapine|[Cc]ocaine'`.

Answer (score 0):

in base R:

```
search_cols <- c("immed_cause_death", "consq1", "consq2", "consq3")
search_words <- c("quetapine", "cocaine")

cbind(df, found = +!!rowSums(Vectorize(grepl)(search_words, df[search_cols])))

  immed_cause_death  consq1 consq2  consq3 found
1         quetapine cocaine heroin    meth     1
2              meth  heroin    thc alcohol     0
3           alcohol    meth   <NA>    <NA>     0
```